# Find Unique values within group of partial matches

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to identify unique instances of a match condition which includes partial matches.

```
HOSTABC
HOSTABC
HOSTABC.domain.com
HOSTABC.domain.com
```

I am trying to count unique instances of a match condition. I have a formula that does this as long as the cells are an EXACT match:

```
=(countif($F$2:$F2,$F2$”*”)=1)+0
```

This formula leaves a “1” for the first instance of the match, and a “0” for all other instances of the match. My problem is that in my example row1 and 2 are BOTH an EXACT match to each other, AND a partial match to rows 3 and 4.

My current formula returns results like this:

```
HOSTABC             1
HOSTABC             0
HOSTABC.domain.com  1
HOSTABC.domain.com  0
```

I would like to see row1 with a 1 and all of the other rows in this example with a 0
Any ideas?

Comment: So are the other examples **always** separated by a `.`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to reformulate in such a way that the formula tests if any of its components appears in the previous cells.

For example, assuming that all your entries with additional items are always separated by dots (.) and have 3 items (HOSTABC.domain.com) as in the case above, something along the following lines may work:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,"="&$F2&"*")>0,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,"="&LEFT($F2,FIND(".",$F2)-1)&"*")>0,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,"="&MID($F2,FIND(".",$F2)+1,FIND(".",$F2,FIND(".",$F2)+1)-FIND(".",$F2)-1)&"*")>0,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,"="&RIGHT($F2,LEN($F2)-FIND(".",$F2,FIND(".",$F2)+1))&"*")>0),0,1)
```

EDIT:

For your follow-up question re. the validity, something along the following lines may work:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(F:F,"="&$F2&"*")>1,COUNTIF(F:F,"="&LEFT($F2,FIND(".",$F2)-1)&"*")>1),"Valid","")
```

Also, I understand from SuperSam's answer that you only Need the hostname (for ex. HOSTABC). The answer above is only checking for this. Additionally, if that's the case, you can simplify my first suggested formula slightly as follows:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,"="&$F2&"*")>0,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,"="&LEFT($F2,FIND(".",$F2)-1)&"*")>0),0,1)
```

Comment: SuperSam, jorgegomez, Thanks so much for your help with this. Both solutions gave me the desired results. Now I have a similar but opposite problem with the same data. All of these hostnames are coming from different network discovery tools and assets inventory databases.

Comment: I have a formula that I use to create a "confidence factor" between the different datasources. Meaning that if the hostname was found in AT LEAST two places it is considered "VALID". My current formula has the same problem that my last one did, in that it only evaluates EXACT matches.  =IF(COUNTIFS(F:F,F2&"*")>1,"Valid","") Can you help me fix this formula as well?

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited my answer above considering this follow-up question and a simplification you can probably make to the first formula I suggested considering that you only Need to check for the hostname (as I understand now)

Comment: You guys are Awesome! I have been struggling with this for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a helper column C for example and write in it this formula
`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)-1),A1)`

A is your Hostname and in column D write the following:

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,"="&C1&"*")=1,1,0)`

Drag the 2 formulas down and you will see row1 with a 1 and all of the other rows in this example with a 0